# Ruby modules and Module#append_features explanation

Tags: ruby, inheritance, module

Lately I bumped into this very interesting post: http://opensoul.org/blog/archives/2011/02/07/concerning-activesupportconcern/ which walks through (and explains) the `ActiveSupport::Concern` source code.

A few questions arose, but the most important was this:

Obviously there's a method called `append_features` which (by the docs at least) says: *"Ruby’s default implementation of this method will add constants, methods, and variables of this module to the base module"*.

I always thought that module works the same as classes in the sense of the method lookup chain - the only difference is that you can't instantiate objects from it, and that it's not defined as a 'superclass' of this class (since a module is not actually a class). meaning that when a class `includes` a module, the module is simply being added as a direct parent in the class's inheritance hierarchy, and as a result, methods which are missing in the including class, will be looked for at the module.

But if that's the case, then what does it mean that `append_features` actually *"adds methods to the base module"*, which means that you can actually prevent this behaviour, by overriding this method (which `ActiveSupport::Concern` actually does).

Can someone create some order in my head?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically, the **`append_features`** is - or should be considered - a **deeply internal ruby method**.

The `Module.include` method is defined *(in the "eval.c" file with the name of [`rb_mod_include`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/9c236f114001fb557fde97632136c84e669e489c/eval.c#L1047))* as a loop, which just calls `mod.append_features` (and then `mod.included`) for every `Module` argument passed to it.

The default **`append_features`** implementation *([`rb_mod_append_features`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/9c236f114001fb557fde97632136c84e669e489c/eval.c#L1029) in "eval.c" file)*, calls the [`rb_include_module`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/9c236f114001fb557fde97632136c84e669e489c/class.c#L823), and this is the method which **does the real job**.

*(Actually the really real job is done by the [`include_modules_at`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/9c236f114001fb557fde97632136c84e669e489c/class.c#L848) few lines below)*

It means that you are perfectly right saying that you can **prevent or break** this basic ruby functionality by overriding the `append_features` (at least if you don't call the `super`).

The `ActiveSupport::Concern` actually calls the `super`, just in some cases it postpones the actual call until the "concerned" module is included by some "non-concerned" one.

**It's usually better to override the `included`** method instead of `append_features`. The `included` is defined as just `"return nil"`, thus the probability of breaking anything is smaller. And that is what the documentation of the `included` method advices.